# Rotate text in custom style renderer in OpenLayers?

Tags: openlayers, style

I would like to have more control of the label placement for polygon geometries in OpenLayers. In some cases, I need to rotate the Label. How does that work if I draw the style on the canvas directly? Currently, the Text just disappears if I apply rotation and the anchor of rotation

My code so far:

```
const interactionLayer = new VectorImageLayer({
    source: featureSource,
    zIndex: Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER,
    style: (feature, resolution) => {
        return new Style({
            renderer: (pxGeometry, state) => {
                if (!isPolygon(pxGeometry)) {
                    return;
                }
                const [x, y] = polylabel(pxGeometry, 1.0);

                const polygon = new Polygon(pxGeometry);

                const olContext = toContext(state.context);

                olContext.setFillStrokeStyle(
                    new Fill({
                        color: "rgba(0,0,0,0.5)",
                    }),
                    new Stroke({
                        color: "#FF0000",
                    })
                );

                olContext.drawGeometry(polygon);

                state.context.save();
              
                state.context.rotate(-Math.PI / 2);
                state.context.translate(x, y);
                
                state.context.fillText(`x: ${x}, y: ${y}`, x, y);

                state.context.restore();
            },
        });
    },
});
```

The result if translating and then apply rotation:

[image]

Comment: Try translating to the required position before rotating the context.

Comment: Did that, see my edit. x and y commin from this lib https://github.com/mapbox/polylabel it's "pole of inaccessibility", in my case just the center of the polygon currently

Comment: You have already translated to x, y so the fillText should be done at 0, 0

Comment: You are right, works as expected, thank you so much. Would accept your answer if you like to answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call `.translate(x, y)` before applying rotation at the required position, and no further `x, y` offset is required in `fillText()` if it has already been translated.

```
            state.context.translate(x, y);
            state.context.rotate(-Math.PI / 2);
            
            state.context.fillText(`x: ${x}, y: ${y}`, 0, 0);
```